Why does total cost not match in the "When and where ads showed" and "Search terms" reports (Google Ads)?
I've been reviewing old data in a Google Ads account.  If I set the date range to Last Month, and go to When and Where Ads Showed, then there are a couple of very expensive ads listed. Let's say they're both £5.
I am looking at the "avg cost" column, so not making the mistake of counting multiple clicks together (which would be my first assumption if someone asked this question).
The Total Cost listed here is, say, £100.
However, when trying to find out what terms triggered these, I go to the Search Terms view.  Here, no ads are listed at £5 and the total cost says £90.
Why do these totals not match and the ads not appear as search terms?  I had wondered if Google had cancelled some stupidly priced clicks it had placed, but the £100 is also listed on the Overview page as that month's cost.
